# How to set a language in speech-synthesis on a website?

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

My problem is that I want to set for my users on websites possibilities to read a text - in the Polish language with Speech-synthesis. But some browsers have not a voice for the Polish language, e.g. Firefox in Windows 7.

Here is my code:

```
let speak = function(text) {    
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    msg.voice = voices[0];
    msg.voiceURI = 'native';
    msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
    msg.rate = 1; // 0.1 to 10
    msg.pitch = 2; //0 to 2
    msg.text = text;
    msg.lang = 'pl-PL';

    msg.onend = function(e) {
      console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.');
    };

    if('speechSynthesis' in window && msg.lang == 'pl-PL') {
        speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    } else {
        window.open('./info-about-browser.html', 'Info about your browser', 'height=350, width=600, top=200, left=200', 'scrollbars=no', 'resizable=no');
    }
}
```

The question is, what I must to do for setting the voice for the Polish language in all browsers? How can I do this?

Thank you for every tip.

Comment: take a look to [Browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Hi @gaetanoM! Thank you for this link. I know that two browsers don't support SpeechSynthesis, and for this, I have the option `if` on my code. But I don't know how to add the option `if` to my code for the situation when the browser has not a Polish language lector. Maybe you know how to do this?

Comment: do you mean something like: voices.find(e => e.lang == 'pl-PL') == undefined?

Comment: Yes, something like this. I want to use this option to read a text on a website only when the Polish voice or speaker is implemented in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If Polish language is unavailable, you cannot rely speechsynthesis on it.
So, two choices:

1. Fallback to a near language : Russian, Czech...
2. Use external services like [Google cloud text to speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/) or [Amazon Polly](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/polly/)

Comment: Another option 2: https://responsivevoice.org/text-to-speech-languages/

Comment: Hi @ManUtopiK! Thank you for these all links - maybe I try one :)